# Regex : referencing an already captured group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am capturing Bar via a named groupA and I would like to re-reference groupA capture to get a second group.

Sample string :

`Foo:Bar Lorem ipsum Bar-564875XC4 dolor sit amet`

Regex to capture `Bar` in groupA :

`Foo:(?<groupA>[^\s]+)`

Question : how to I complete this regex to re-capture `<groupA>` and get `564875XC4` in `<groupB>` ?

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I would write your regex in C# as:

```
Foo:(?<groupA>\w+)(?: \w+)* \k<groupA>-(?<groupB>\w+)
```

More generally, you could also just use a numbered backreference:

```
Foo:(?<groupA>\w+)(?: \w+)* \1-(?<groupB>\w+)
```

### Demo

Explanation:

- `Foo:` match "Foo-"
- `(?<groupA>\w+)` match and capture first word in `<groupA>`
- `(?: \w+)*` then match space followed by a word, zero or more tkmes
- match a single space
- `\k<groupA>` match the first captured word (again)
- `-` match "-"
- `(?<groupB>\w+)` match and capture term of interest in `<groupB>`

Comment: Can you can use a numbered back-reference to reference a named capture group?

Comment: Numbered back reference will do for my use-case. Any possibility to reference groupA by it's name ?

Comment: What is your regex flavor/language?

Comment: C# but that's not very important. Just found by myself, thanks to your first answer !

Comment: Check the updated answer for an exact C# regex.

Answer (score 0):

Answer with back-reference by name:

`Foo:(?<groupA>\w+)(?: \w+)* \g<groupA>-(?<groupB>\w+)`

[**Demo with named back-reference**](https://regex101.com/r/uLdqSK/1)